# convert a projectionlist to json format in java spring boot application

Tags: java, json, spring

how can i convert a projectionlist to json format in spring?

```
    Session session = getSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentFeedback.class);
    ProjectionList projlist =Projections.projectionList();
    projlist.add(Projections.property("feedbackStatus"));
    projlist.add(Projections.property("totalFeedback"));
    criteria.setProjection(projlist);
```

i want the resulting fetched db data shown as like below

```
{"feedName":value,"qty":value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use: query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP) in the following manner,

```
    String HQL_QUERY = "select comp.id as comp_id, comp.name as comp_name from Company comp";
    Query query = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY);
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

    List<?> rows = query.list();    
    System.out.println("Selected row count : " + rows.size());

    for (Object row : rows) {
      System.out.println(row); //Each row is a map of properties in the query
                   //with key as alias and property as value
    }
```

for reference Click [here](http://bethecoder.com/applications/tutorials/hibernate/hibernate-query-language/map-result-transformer.html)